# How to fix misplaced type in Typescript without using keyword "any"

Tags: javascript, typescript, cryptojs

I have a TypeScript project that uses CryptoJS library. The linter shows that I quote **Property 'sigBytes' does not exist on type 'DecryptedMessage'.** Where I can with no problem log this property into console. The code that yields this message:

```
let dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, this.key, {iv: this.iv});
console.log(dec.sigBytes); // There it logs the property correctly
```

I got types definition from npm. I tried setting up variable dec as CryptoJS.LibWordArray like this:

```
let dec: CryptoJS.LibWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, this.key, {iv: this.iv});
```

But the linter shows "Type 'DecryptedMessage' is missing the following properties from type 'LibWordArray': sigBytes, words"

The code runs fine, however I wonder about the best practice to fix this or similiar issues. Using any yields no warnings,

```
let dec: CryptoJS.LibWordArray = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, this.key, {iv: this.iv});
```

but I'm not sure thats a good practice

Comment: The best option would be to [submit a pull request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/crypto-js) to DefinitelyTyped to add in the types that should exist, but don't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved the issue with keyword *as* (thanks to @Budaa suggestion):

```
let dec = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(text, this.key, {iv: this.iv}) as CryptoJS.LibWordArray;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using type assertion: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions